# f# getting list of possible discriminated union item

Tags: f#

I am creating a simple DSL with multiple discriminated unions(DU) . There is building block DU and higher DUs are build on top of lower ones.

Now I want to create  UI where user can build a text which matches my DSL. to UI I don't want to express my full grammar, but show only possible actions that can be done. So I need a way to figure out from my hierarchical DU, what are other possible states that user can do.

sample input text `(1 + (2 * 3))`

```
type Expression =
   | Constant of int
   | Add of Expression * Expression
   | Mul of expression * Expression
```

so when user starts, I have to return a list saying only `Constant` can be used.
when user passes (constant ) as his current state, I have to tell you can `add/Mul` (which is expression) and so on.

I want to represent a structure which says, current state and possible states to go from in a type safe way. Is there a way to solve this kind of problem in f#

Comment: How do you define type-safe? Add / Mul requires two arguments. How do you represent those?

Comment: Can you expand your example? I'm not sure what is the case.

Comment: type reference means, if I am missing any state, I should get compile time error. If there are states (defined as Discriminated Union) and events to change state, is there a programmatic way to get list of all events (and if any event what possible state it can go to).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`FSharpType.GetUnionCases`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/reflection.unioncaseinfo-class-%5Bfsharp%5D).  You can use this as follows:

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type Expression =
   | Constant of int
   | Add of Expression * Expression
   | Mul of Expression * Expression

typeof<Expression> |> FSharpType.GetUnionCases|> Dump |> ignore
```

LinqPad for the above [here](http://share.linqpad.net/d3pena.linq)